# Why cURL is timed out?

Tags: php, curl

I want to fetch the result of a webpage, exactly like a simple user, through a browser. I setted the headers and the sended cookies of the request, to which I got with fiddler4. Last night it's worked, but now it's throw cURL error 28, request timed out.

Here is the code what I used:

```
function cURL($url){
    $cURL=curl_init();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,de;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2";
    $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch";
    $header[] = "Pragma: ";
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'action=verChau');
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'Cookie: __gfp_64b=mgK79a4qc_M9RH4eFToSbGkkxUWaWD2tKPQ51RreN8r.A7; PHPSESSID=780d83cb35c5b82098e33fde9c101d08; __atuvc=0%7C4%2C0%7C5%2C1%7C6%2C6%7C7%2C1%7C8; cTest=1; resDone20101213=1; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.307256553.1418233339; _goa3=eyJ1IjoiMTQxMjEyNDEwODM2NDE4MTU4NzAxNiIsImgiOiJCQzI0OEVFRC5kc2wucG9vbC50ZWxla29tLmh1IiwicyI6MTQxODMzODgwMDAwMH0=; _goa3TC=eyI1NjM2NCI6MTQyNTEzMjMwNDE2OCwiMzEzNDUzMiI6MTQyNTE0ODk1NDg2M30=; _goa3TS=e30=');
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $html=curl_exec($cURL);
    if ($html === false){
        echo "cURL exception: ".curl_errno($cURL).": ".curl_error($cURL);
    }
    curl_close($cURL);
    return $html;
}
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: I can't see any error with your code. It's working. May be you've been banned, you're having problems with firewall or you are experimenting some sort of network problem

Comment: When I fetched an other site, it's working correctly. Maybe the owner of the site make some changes, which is banned me? Last night it's worked fine, but today it's time out when fetch that page. What should I change to fetch that page?